# validator.js is not uglified correctly

Tags: javascript, validation, webpack

I have an Express+React app and I use validator.js.

When I uglify my js with webpackUglifyJsPlugin, I see the following error:

This library (validator.js) validates strings only

Is it a plugin problem or I can fix it somehow?

Thanks, Alex A.

Comment: Does the error come with a traceback?

Comment: Nope. But I use it only in one place and I know where it fails exactly. The problem is that when it's not uglified, all works correctly

Answer (score 0):

By validating strings only means that it requires you to pass a parameter as a String for it to be validated.

E.g

```js
validator.isFloat("121.21"); // instead of 
validator.isFloat(121.21);
```